# vCard Instant messaging syntax for import into Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts-api, vcf-vcard, instant-messaging

Anyone has any idea what is the vCard syntax for Instant Messaging to use when importing the vCard into Google Contacts? or Google Contacts ignore and does not allow Instant Messaging data from vCard to be added in the record?

Google Contacts CardDAV use vCard v3.0 encoding format as stated in `https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6352`.

Tried importing a vCard 3.0 with the following Instant Messaging syntax but could not work
- `IMPP:aim:johndoe@aol.com` (This syntax works when the vCard is imported into iOS)
- `IM:aim:johndoe@aol.com` (Tried this because Google Contacts API use IM)

If I manually input the Instant Messaging field data via editing of record in the mobile phone, it works. It works too when manually input data in Google Contacts web UI.

Tried exporting a record from Google Contacts with Instant Messaging field, the exported vCard does not contain data for the Instant Messaging field.